# compare files in loop

Tags: command-line

I have a folder `testcases`, with various subfolders. In each subfolder there are 3 files:

1. testcase.csv
2. testcase64.csv
3. testcaseMac.csv.

How do I loop through all the subfolders and compare 3 files in each folder - whether the three files have the same content or different?

Comment: in what way would you like the result presented; what if some files are the same, some different? what if there are (in one file category) three or four versions? Or would you compare only the three files *in one folder / per folder*, should the difference be specified etc.

Comment: To compare whether it's the same, `cmp` would be faster than 'diff'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`diff`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/diff.1.html) command:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
for dir in testcases/*
do
    if [[ -d $dir ]]
    then
        cd $dir 
        diff testcase.csv testcase64.csv -q > /dev/null || echo "$dir/testcase.csv and $dir/testcase64.csv differ."
        diff testcase.csv testcaseMac.csv -q > /dev/null || echo "$dir/testcase.csv and $dir/testcaseMac.csv differ."
        diff testcaseMac.csv testcase64.csv -q > /dev/null || echo "$dir/testcaseMac.csv and $dir/testcase64.csv differ."
        cd -
    fi
done
```